# Docker execute shell command in ADD instruction's src_path

Tags: docker, shell, dockerfile

I have a bunch of folders named `1/` `2/` `3/` in a directory which contains a dockerfile.
I'm trying to add the latest folder `3/` to the docker container using the docker add instruction in the dockerfile.

I came up with this `ls -r | grep "[0-9]" | head -1` to give the folder with highest valued name. But I'm unable to execute it in the docker add instruction.

**DOCKERFILE:**

```
FROM tensorflow/serving:2.8.0

WORKDIR /models

ADD ls -r | grep "[0-9]" | head -1 ./

ENV MODEL_NAME NumPlateDetector
```

**ERROR:**

```
ADD failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat ls: file does not exist
```

Any tips on how i can include that folder or get the ADD instruction to execute that line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Original Answer:**

That feature does not exist, you will need to template your Dockerfile. For example:

```
# contents of "Dockerfile.template"

FROM tensorflow/serving:2.8.0

WORKDIR /models

ADD ${directory_to_add}

ENV MODEL_NAME NumPlateDetector
```

And then in a shell script:

```
export directory_to_add="$(ls -r | grep "[0-9]" | head -1 ./)"

envsubst < Dockerfile.template > Dockerfile
```

Reference to Dockerfile ADD instruction for completeness:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add

**Updated Alternative**:

In regards to the comment by @david-maze, you can pass in a build arg if you prefer:

```
FROM tensorflow/serving:2.8.0

ARG directory_to_add

WORKDIR /models

ADD $directory_to_add

ENV MODEL_NAME NumPlateDetector
```

And then modify your build command:

```
export directory_to_add="$(ls -r | grep "[0-9]" | head -1 ./)"

docker image build --build-arg directory_to_add="$directory_to_add" ...
```

Comment: Good reproducible approach, Thanks :)

Comment: Using a Dockerfile [`ARG`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) might save you a step here.